# Ducks highest body temperature

Tags: zoology, ornithology

Normal body temperature for ducks are 106-108°F (41.1-42.2°C).
Young ducks 102-106°F (38.9-41.1°C).

How hot can a duck's body temperature get?

Possible causes are fever and viruses, as well as stress hypothermic response.

Will it ever reach 113°F (45°C)?
What will be the cause?
How common is it?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please visit the [help] and take a [tour] for more information on what we do here and what make a good question and answer. Please also note the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) policy. In that light - what have you found out about this. A quick search leads to some very relevant papers with great detail as the top links.

Comment: The only thing I found so far was temperatures caused by injecting the duck with different pathogenic constituents for testing purposes, it also says "When they were handled to apply treatments, the ducks developed stress hyperthermic responses", but not so sure how to read those charts, looks like it reached +-43°C due to the injection. Not sure how common this is. I heard that it can reach 45°C, but cannot verify it nor the cause.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51150900_Body_temperature_responses_of_Pekin_ducks_Anas_platyrhynchos_domesticus_exposed_to_different_pathogens

Comment: You can probably generalize from other birds - just as you can for most mammals. Max I have seen is 46 C being fatal.